# Text (Special unicode, like &#8657;) not vertically centered in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Given the following css code, the text (arrow) is vertically centered in Chrome while not in IE11, could someone tell me why and how can I achieve the same effects in IE11?

```css
span {
  display: block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<span>&#8657;</span>
```

Screenshots:

Chrome:
[image]

IE11:
[image]

Comment: Please add some screenshots so we can better assist.

Comment: @DaniSpringer, edited, thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely and positively sure that both browsers use the same font for this character? I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2aotosbp/1/) that sets a specific font and size and line height, and I don't see any differences.

Comment: @MrLister, I got my two screenshots just by opening this StackOverFlow page in Chrome/IE11. And when opening your fiddle in Chrome/IE11, there are also differences: one vertically centered while the other not

Comment: That leaves the question, what fonts are being used? What do your browsers' inspect tools say?

Comment: @MrLister, both are 'Times New Roman` when I inspect the `<span` tag.

Comment: @HaibaraAi Hm. On my computer, 'Times New Roman' doesn't contain the ⇑ character.

Comment: @MrLister, thanks and that's the point! Please see my posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the computed `font-family` is `Times New Roman` as the inspect view shows:

[image]

However, looking through the [supported unicode characters by the `Times New Roman` font](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/times_new_roman/list.htm), we find [`⇑ (U+21D1)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21d1/index.htm)is not supported by `Times New Roman`. In this case, browser is free to choose which font to use, and we have no idea how the characters would be aligned (since we don't know which fallback font the browser has chosen to use internally), that causes the behavior varies from browsers.

So how to make it vertically centered? One simple method would be explicitly specifying a `font-family` which contains `⇑ (U+21D1)`, for example, [`Cambria`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/cambria/list.htm)

```css
span {
  display: block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: Cambria;
}
```

```html
<span>&#8657;</span>
```